# R - plot vertical profile

Tags: r, plot, profile

I have measurements of CH4 concentration with depth:

```
df <- structure(list(Depth = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 17L), .Label = c("0", "10", 
"12", "14", "16", "18", "2", "20", "22", "24", "26", "28", "30", 
"32", "4", "6", "8", "AR"), class = "factor"), Conc_CH4 = c(4.30769230769231, 
23.1846153846154, 14.5615384615385, 21.1769230769231, 16.2615384615385, 
132.007692307692, 5.86923076923077, 389.353846153846, 823.023076923077, 
948.684615384615, 1436.56923076923, 1939.88461538462, 26.2769230769231, 
27.5538461538462, 19.6461538461538)), .Names = c("Depth", "Conc_CH4"
), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I need to create a plot like this:

[image]

But I have some problems: the factors in my data are in the wrong order, and I don't know how to plot this kind of data using ggplot2.

Any ideas?

Comment: A grouping variable is missing in "df", no?

Comment: Hmmm that's all I have. You mean I should create one or it looks like it is missing one?

Comment: If it's only one measurement, just `order` "df" according to "Depth".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not convert `Depth` to a number and plot?

```
ggplot(transform(df, Depth=as.numeric(as.character(df$Depth))),
                 aes(x=Conc_CH4, y=Depth)) +
    geom_line() + scale_y_reverse()
```

The `as.numeric(as.character(...))` is because your `Depth` is a factor and calling `as.numeric` directly converts factors differently than character to string.

The `scale_y_reverse` reverses the y scale.

If your actual data has a depth of "AR" in it, you'll have to omit them or otherwise handle them.

[image]

Comment: Cool! I learned two tricks: how to reorder numeric factors that were originally characters and how to use `scale_y_reverse()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with base plotting functions (you reverse the limits of `ylim`):

```
df$Depth <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Depth))
df <- df[order(df$Depth),]
plot(Depth~Conc_CH4, df, t="l", ylim=rev(range(df$Depth)))
```

[image]

Comment: Marc, by using `as.numeric` we lose the original values of `Depth`.

Comment: Marc, this is really neat and exactly what I wanted. I wish I could choose two answers, but the other one employs `ggplot2`, which is the package I usually use for plotting my data. Many thanks though.